# Creating a Laravel Eloquent where if main model's grand child is 0, do not include in return

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to query a relation model on the 3rd level. Using the code below, I am able to eager load 3rd model data from MainModel. However, if 3rdModel is empty, MainModel grandparent should not be included.

Below is the hierarchy of the model I am trying to process:

```
MainModel
    2ndModel
        3rdModel
```

Below is the eloquent code I am trying to work:

```
return $query->first_model_queries
->with('has_many_2nd_model', function ($query) use ($array_of_ids) {
    return $query->whereHas('has_many_3rd_model', function ($query) use ($array_of_ids) {
        return $query->whereIn('2ndModel_id', $array_of_ids);
    }, '=', count($array_of_ids));
});

MainModel.php
/**
* @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
*/
public function has_many_2nd_model()
{
    return $this->hasMany(2ndModel::class, 'first_model_id', 'id')->orderBy('id');
}


2ndModel.php
/**
* @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
*/
public function has_many_3rd_model()
{
    return $this->hasMany(3rdModel::class, '2nd_model_id', 'id')->orderBy('id');
}
```

query value:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "2ndModel": [],
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "2ndModel": [
            {
                "id": 8,
                "3rdModel": [
                    {
                        "name": 3rdModelValue,
                    },
                ],
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "2ndModel": [],
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "2ndModel": [
            {
                "id": 15,
                "3rdModel": [
                    {
                        "name": 3rdModelValue,
                    },
                ],
            }
        ],
    },
]
```

Id 1 and Id 3 should no longer be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use withWhereHas like below:

```
return $query->first_model_queries
    ->withWhereHas('has_many_2nd_model', function ($query) use ($array_of_ids) {
        $query->withWhereHas('has_many_3rd_model', function ($query) use ($array_of_ids) {
            $query->whereIn('2ndModel_id', $array_of_ids);
        }, '=', count($array_of_ids));
    });
```